# Django modelform charField con choices, mostrar valor en vez de clave

Tags: django

Estoy trabajando con Django 1.10.6, estoy creando un **modelForm** con un **CharField** con un atributo **choices**:

**model**:

```
class myModel(models.Model, object):
    ASSIGNED = 'AS'
    NOT_ASSIGNED = 'NA'
    INVALID = 'IN'
    MIGRATED = 'MI'
    STATES = ((ASSIGNED, 'Asignada'), (NOT_ASSIGNED, 'No asignada'), (MIGRATED, 'Migrada'), (INVALID, 'Aceptada'))

    state = models.CharField(verbose_name="Estado", max_length=2, choices=STATES)
    ...
```

**modelform**:

```
class MifareCardMigrationAssignationForm(forms.ModelForm, object):
    ...
    state = forms.CharField(label="Estado", help_text="Estado de migración", disabled=True)
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = MifareCardMigration
        fields = ('legacy_number', 'plate', 'new_card', 'phone_number', 'state')
```

El problema lo tengo al editar un objeto en el Django admin, en el campo *state* quiero mostrar su **valor**, pero aparece su **clave**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como puedo cambiar este comportamiento??

Gracias!!

Comment: Please translate your question to Spanish.

Comment: Cambia el `'state'` por `'get_state_display'`

Comment: German, en fields cambie `'state'` por `'get_state_display'` pero tira este error: `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (get_state_display) specified for MifareCardMigration`